# How to upload file.mp3 to firebase storage in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework, base64, firebase-storage

I am creating an audio recording function in my ionic app. I am using media plugin:

```
$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-media
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/media
```

I can record the audio and play it successfully like this:

```
constructor(private media: Media,private base64: Base64) {

this.file = this.media.create('file.mp3');

}

 record_audio(){

this.file.startRecord();
}
```

to uplaod to firebase I cannot directly upload the file.mp3, looks like I need to convert it to Blob or base64 first so I tried doing this but it says "MediaObject cannot be assigned to string":

```
let filePath: string = 'this.file.mp3'; 
this.base64.encodeFile(filePath).then((base64File: string) => {
console.log(base64File);
}, (err) => {
console.log(err);
});
```

The objective is to upload the recorded audio file to firebase. to do that I need to convert this file.mp3 to base64.

Answer (score 0):

```
      startRecording() {
    console.log("Started Recording");
    this.recording = true;
    this.file.createFile(this.file.tempDirectory, 'my_file.m4a', true).then(() => {
      const audio: MediaObject = this.media.create(this.file.tempDirectory.replace(/^file:\/\//, '') + 'my_file.m4a');
      console.log("Audio assigned to constant audio media object");
      console.log(audio);
      this.audio = audio;
      console.log("Audio assigned to this.audio media object");
      console.log(this.audio);
      this.audio.startRecord();
      this.listenToAudioEvents();
      window.setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.recording) this.stopRecording();
      }, 10000);
    });
  }

  listenToAudioEvents() {
    this.audio.onStatusUpdate.subscribe(status => {
      console.log("Status of this.audio updated");
      console.log(status);
      if (status == 4 && this.playingAudio) {
        console.log("Time to stop playback")
        this.stopPlayback();
      }
    });
  }

  stopRecording() {
    this.audio.stopRecord();
    console.log("Stopped Recording");
    console.log(this.audio);
    this.recording = false;
    this.audioReady = true;
    this.audio.getDuration();
    console.log("Audio Duration: " + this.duration);
    console.log("Audio Duration Property: " + this.audio.duration);
  }

  playAudio() {
    console.log("Playing Audio");
    this.playingAudio = true;
    this.audio.play();
  }

  stopPlayback() {
    console.log("Stopping Playback");
    this.playingAudio = false;
    this.audio.stop();
  }

  uploadAudio() {
    console.log("Uploading record");
    this.storeRecord().subscribe((downloadURL) => {
      console.log("Finished storing record");
      console.log("Download URL is " + downloadURL);
      this.audioURL = downloadURL;
      this.audioURLReady = true;
    });
  }

  storeRecord() {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      console.log('Saving record');
      const filePath = `${this.file.tempDirectory}my_file.m4a`;
      console.log("Path to record is " + filePath);
      const readFile: any = window['resolveLocalFileSystemURL'];
      return readFile(filePath, (fileEntry) => {
        return fileEntry.file((file) => {
          const fileReader = new FileReader();
          fileReader.onloadend = (result: any) => {
            let arrayBuffer = result.target.result;
            let blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer)], { type: 'audio/m4a' });
            console.log("Blob is ");
            console.log(blob);
            var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('content/' + this.firebase.user.uid + '/my-file.m4a');
            console.log("Storage reference is " + storageRef);
            var uploadTask = storageRef.put(blob);
            console.log('Upload started:');
            uploadTask.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
              console.log("state changed");
              let percent = uploadTask.snapshot.bytesTransferred / uploadTask.snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
              console.log(percent + "% done");
            }, (e) => {
              console.error(e);
              observer.error(e);
            }, () => {
              var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
              console.log('Storage Download URL:' + downloadURL);
              observer.next(downloadURL);
            });
          };
          fileReader.onerror = (e: any) => {
            console.error(e);
            observer.error(e);
          };
          fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
        }, (e) => {
          console.error(e);
          observer.error(e);
        });
      }, (e) => {
        console.error(e);
        observer.error(e);
      });
    });
  }

  downloadAudio() {
    console.log("Downloading Audio")
    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.fileTransfer.create();
    var destPath = (cordova.file.externalDataDirectory || cordova.file.dataDirectory) + "my_file.m4a"
    fileTransfer.download(this.audioURL, destPath, ).then((entry) => {
      let rawAudioURI = entry.toURL();
      this.audioURI = rawAudioURI.replace(/^file:\/\//, '/private');
      this.audioURIReady = true;
      console.log("Audio URI: " + this.audioURI);
    }, (error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
  }

  playAudioURI() {
    console.log("Playing AudioURI");
    let downloadedAudio: MediaObject = this.media.create(this.audioURI);
    console.log("Downloaded audio: " + downloadedAudio);
    downloadedAudio.play();
  }
}
```